# Is monism (distinct from monotheism) a form of shirk?

Tags: quran, shirk, soul, monotheism

A definition of *monism* is

> a theory or doctrine that denies the existence of a distinction or duality in... God and the world.

In Islam, *shirk* is defined as

> idolatry or polytheism, which means deification, or worship of deity, gods, or anything other than Allah.

It seems to be the case that monism is a form of shirk because monism asserts that the world (including its inhabitants) and Allah are a part of the same entity. Indeed, the Qur'an repeatedly makes assertions like in An-Naml (27:63)

> Is there any god with Allah? Exalted is Allah above all that they associate as partners to Him.

The only possible argument that I can find in favor of monism in the Qur'an is Sad (38:72) where it says

> So, when I have fashioned [Adam] and breathed into him from *my soul* then fall down to him prostrate.

This phrase "my soul" specifically uses the word "Ruhi" in Arabic, for which I have seen several translations, including spirit, soul and even Gabriel (the last one is unlikely here of course). I don't know the meaning of the word and I doubt anyone else does either, as it it said in Al-Isra (17:85) that

> And they ask you about the *Ruhi*. Say: the *Ruhu* is of the Command of my Lord [meaninig the knowledge of which is only with my Lord] and you have not been given of knowledge but a little.

It is this question of "human divinity" that I have been pondering, especially because it seems to be a rising belief among "spiritual" non-Muslims (though this is just a personal impression). I am fairly certain that it is not an acceptable belief in Islam, but just to be sure, **can someone let me know the correct interpretation of Sad (38:72) as quoted, and what Islam thinks of monism in general?**

Comment: The part about Sad (38:72) is answered at the following link but I am still curious about whether Islamic scriptures directly address monism: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56936/if-allah-blew-part-of-his-soul-into-adam-does-that-mean-that-adam-is-part-of-all